# Why isnt this global variable being updated in python 2.7 even tho I am using the global keyword?

Tags: python-2.7, function, callback, global-variables, python-pika

I have a callback function which returns the body of a AMQP message as each message is received. I would like to be able to assign the content of the body to a global variable and then work with it further on in my program.

I have created a global variable at the top of my script and have used the global keyword within the callback function which I understand should allow me to update the global variable at the top of my script, however when I import the 'global variable' from another script I get the original value of 'test' returned rather than the current value of body from within the callback function...

Consumer.py

```
**python/pika imports and credentials go here**

T_MSG = "test" # create global variable

def main():
    logging.basicConfig()

    (username, password) = open(CREDENTIALS_FILE).read().splitlines()
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username, password)
    params = pika.ConnectionParameters(AMQP_HOST, AMQP_PORT, AMQP_EXCHANGE, credentials)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)

    channel = connection.channel()

    channel.queue_declare(queue=QUEUE_NAME, durable=False)

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        #print "received message: %r" % body

        global T_MSG # Define that I want to work with the global variable

        #assert isinstance(body, object)

        T_MSG = str(body) # assign the value of body to the global variable 

        print T_MSG # this prints out the body as expected

        return T_MSG
        #ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

    #channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)

    channel.basic_consume(callback, queue=QUEUE_NAME, no_ack=False)
    print 'waiting for new messages on queue: '
    channel.start_consuming()
```

Importer.py

```
from consumer import T_MSG

print T_MSG # this prints the original value of T_MSG e.g. 'Test'
```

I cant understand why the value of T_MSG is not being updated from within the callback function as I can clearly see that the print statement is printing the correct value of body - but even though I have declared this as global within the callback function, when I import the value of T_MSG and try to print it, I get the originally assigned value of 'Test' rather than the content of the body I am expecting...

I am under the impression that each time the callback function receives a message and 'processes' it, the new value of body should be assigned to the T_MSG (global) variable and thus I should be able to import it into my importer.py script - but this isn't working and everything I have read just points to using the global keyword within the function to make this so...

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After importing, you need to call consumer.main() to get your variable changed:

```
import consumer
print consumer.T_MSG  # here you should see the original value
consumer.main()
print consumer.T_MSG  # now it will be updated
```

Comment: Thank you Raf - this works! I'm trying to update the value of the T_MSG variable every time a new body is received rather than just print it, but I imagine that this will work as needed for that too - many thanks for the swift reply!

Comment: Your module.py seems correct, T_MSG will be updated. It is just your example Importer.py which was missing the call of the function. When you load the module, T_MSG and main() will be loaded, but main(), or any other function in it, will not be called, you'll have to make the call yourself.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! I will go on to use split on the body received which is now T_MSG (as this is a delimited string) and I will then assign the components to other variables which I will then use to do math and other things within my program - basically I needed to be able to use the content of body/T_MSG so that my variable values are updated as soon as a new message is received - what you have shown should allow me to do this with a bit of tinkering - many thanks!

Comment: Ahh, I seem to have hit a snag - when I call consumer.main() - it seems to pull the full callback functionality into the importer.py script - this means that by just calling 'consumer.main() ' it pulls the whole callback function into the script rather than just the T_MSG variable... maybe I can still work with this, I will have a play and see what I can do...

Comment: you would have to add more details to your question. for example, how exactly is consumer.py being used? is there any other process calling it? if you 'import consumer' the whole module will be imported. if you want only the variable then yes you should do 'from consumer import variable'. but then you need something else calling your callback function to update the string you want.

Comment: The idea is that consumer.py runs and consumes messages from an amqp server (RabbitMQ) - the messages are picked up by the above script, as comma delimited strings and I am trying to work out how I can consume these strings, split them into fields and then use the fields in another python script and perform calculations using their values - but I also need the values updated each time a new amqp/RabbitMQ message is received,  I know how to split the strings but cant seem to set the split values to global variables outside of the call-back function which actually receives the original message.